# MySQL Workbench - Foreign Keys tab not working

Tags: foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I have a scheme, having 2 tables:

Accessory1

[image]

Service

[image]

Now I want `Service.service_accessory` to refer to `Accessory1.accessory_id`. So I go to `Foreign Keys` tab in `Service` table, name the FK, pick `Referenced Table` on the left.

But when I choose `service_accessory` to refer to `accessory_id`, it keeps unpicking my selection. My screen record [here](https://youtu.be/l6DfVbMFtfs).

Is there something wrong with the tool? Or something wrong with my steps?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatypes INT(10) and INT(11) look like they're not identical.

And the MYSQL reference manual says :

"Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referencedkey must have similar data types. The size andsign of integer types must be the same".

Comment: I made 2 changes: 1) In `Accessory1`, I changed `accessory_id` from `INT(10)` to `INT(11)`; 2) In `Service`, make `service_accessory` to `Unsigned` (to make it match with `accessory_id` data type. It works just fine. Thanks a lot!